# GSON Has Different Behaviour in Unit Test vs Deployed Code

Tags: java, unit-testing, gson

I am trying to integrate GSON into an existing project to serialise and de-serialise a pre-existing complex data structure consisting of mostly POJOs. I have written a JUnit test to verify this is successful as follows:

```
@Test
public void testJsonSerialization() throws Exception {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    MyObject myObject = generateMyObject();

    //Convert to JSON
    String json = gson.toJson(myObject);

    //Convert to MyObject
    MyObject newMyObject = gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);

    //Compare
    assertEquals(myObject, newMyObject);
}
```

This unit test passes successfully, but when used in my production code the de-serialisation fails due to missing no-arg constructors:

```
public void onHttpPostRequest(HttpRequest request){
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    try{
        validateHttpPostRequest(request);
        MyObject myObject = gson.fromJson(request.getContentAsString(), MyObject.class);

        //continue processing request
    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.warn("Failed to parse incoming Request", e);
    }
}
```

Resulting in the following exception:

```
Failed to parse incoming Request
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class com.example.MyChildObject. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$14.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:228)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1003)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter$GsonContextImpl.deserialize(TreeTypeAdapter.java:162)
at com.example.Message$JsonAdapter.deserialize(Message.java:230)
at com.example.Message$JsonAdapter.deserialize(Message.java:188)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:69)
at com.google.gson.TypeAdapter$1.read(TypeAdapter.java:199)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:817)
```

I have absolutely no problem with fixing the issue but as the unit test is not representative we cannot be 100% certain that we have not missed any classes in our complex datatype.

Is there any reason why GSON behaviour may be different in a unit test compared to production code?

Comment: Have you verified constructor visibility? Could be that the no-args constructor is visible in the test class's package but not in the onHttpPostRequest()'s package. Note that the issue appears to be not with MyObject, but with MyChildObject.

Comment: @ObiObi The issue is that MyChildObject doesn't have a no-args constructor at all so I'm unsure how the unit test is even passing. In some cases child objects are in different packages.

Comment: It looks like the exception stack trace is cut off, there should be a "Caused by:". I assume that cause is `UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot allocate com.example.MyChildObject` thrown by Gson's internal UnsafeAllocator. If no no-arg constructor exists, Gson falls back to using the JDK internal `sun.misc.Unsafe` to construct the object. However apparently in your production environment that class is not present. We would need more information e.g. Java version to find out why that is the case or how to solve it.

Comment: Apologies for not getting back to you sooner. The problem is indeed related to `sun.misc.Unsafe` not being available in our production environment. This was due to a security manager being used in our application server. I have added a security manager in our unit tests and it behaves the same as our production code.